# Prove that $f$ is an isomorphism if $n$ is odd and $f = (det A \cdot A, det A)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Define a map $f:O(n)\rightarrow SO(n)\times \{+1,-1\}$ as follows: $f(A)=($det($A$)$\cdot A$, det $A$).

If $n$ is odd, prove that $f$ is an isomorphism.

I know that first I must show that $f$ is a homomorphism. 
$f(A*B) = f(A)\cdot f(B)$. 
Let $A, B \in O(n),$ then
\begin{align} 
f(A*B) &= ((\det A*B) * (A * B),(\det A*B))\\
&=((\det A)*(\det B) * A * B, (\det A) * (\det B))\\
&=((\det A) * A *(\det B) * B, (\det A) * (\det B)) \\
&=((\det A) * A , (\det A))\cdot ((\det B) * B, (\det B))\\ 
&= f(A)\cdot f(B)
\end{align}

But how do I show that this is an isomorphism?

Comment: Try to define an inverse? $g:SO(n) \times \{1,-1\} \to O(n)$ defined by $g(A,\pm 1) = \pm A$. Now, show (assuming $n$ is odd!), that $g= f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave injectivity for you to prove (this is straight forward and does not use the fact that $n$ is odd).

**Surjective:** take $(A,x)\in SO(n)\times\{-1,1\}$. If $x=1$ then we just have $f(A)=(A,x)$, and if $x=-1$ then we have $f(-A)=((-1)^n(-A),(-1)^n)=(A,x)$ since $n$ odd.

Comment: If it is even then the map doesn't land in the co-domain.

Comment: @JustinYoung yes, good note. That is essential captured in my argument for surjectivity (if $\det(A)=-1$ then $\det(\det(A)A)=(-1)^n\det(A)=1$ when $n$ odd); my note on injectivity not needing $n$ odd is more about how you don't actually use the fact that $n$ is odd directly to prove injectivity.